# Libgdx InputProcessor - Determine if you swiped off of a keyDown

Tags: android, mobile, libgdx

Working on a mobile game at the moment and was having difficulty getting the back button on android devices to function as I want it to.

Here's the scenario: You click down on the back button, realize you don't actually want to go back so you swipe up (while still pressed) onto the game screen, thus negating the back button being pushed.

I'm using InputProcessor and i have keyDown and keyUp. The problem is, i'm not sure how to use these two together so that when i swipe off the back button it doesn't go back.

I have been able to get the back button to do the other functionality i want (such as not exiting the app and going between screens and such), just stuck on this one scenario.

Any help is much appreciated.

Edit: This functionality can be seen in the facebook mobile app. If you click on the back button swipe off of it to the mainscreen, the app doesn't exit.

Comment: either implement the exit event, use touch events with touchdragged or just use a click listener. Afaik the clicklistener only fires clicked when the button goes up when the finger is over it.

Comment: @p.streef thanks for the reply. I tried using touchDragged, however when i moved off of the android back button onto the play screen it didn't get triggered, so it wasn't doing anything. I'll try using the click listener and see if that'll solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know exactly the Syntax for Mobile development but I figure your best course of action is to create a Boolean willExit, and instantiate it as true, and in the KeyUp() function put and if (willExit) statement. Now you can have it run through the block KeyUp() without doing anything if willExit = false. From there you just set willExit to false whenever the condition is met, such as in your case when Swiping.

Answer (score 0):

Simply in the KeyDown use the switch statement to see if the it is the back button or not.

If it is the back button, check if the screen is touched.

As simple as that.

BTW sorry for not providing code snippets.